# Having trouble validating string input from input() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to make a Tic-Tac-Toe game in python, using pycharm community version 2019 and python 3.8. In the beginning of the game, I want to allow the player to choose whether they will play with 'X' or 'O'.

```
def player_turn():
    asking_4_character = True
    while asking_4_character:
        character = input("Who do you want to play as? X or O? ")
        if character != 'X' or character != 'O':
            print("Invalid character. Try again.")
        else:
            asking_4_character = False
```

However when I enter "X" or "O", it goes to the error message. I have went through the debugger and can confirm this happens ([picture attached for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4zuL.jpg)). Can anyone explain why? I know there might be ways to achieve using other functions, but I want to understand why this method isn't working.

Comment: Every conceivable character is either unequal to `X`, or unequal to `O`.  You want `and` instead of `or` there.

Comment: If `character` is `X` then it's not `O`.

Answer (score 0):

It should read "if character not X and character not O"

```
def player_turn():
    asking_4_character = True
    while asking_4_character:
        character = input("Who do you want to play as? X or O? ")
        if character != 'X' and character != 'O':
            print("Invalid character. Try again.")
        else:
            asking_4_character = False
```

And you can break early

```
def player_turn():
    while True:
        character = input("Who do you want to play as? X or O? ")
        if character in ("X", "O"):
            break
```

Comment: I see the mistake. So it's because of 'or' that the if statement was always evaluating to false since if you enter O then it is equal to O and vice versa (if you enter 'X')?

Comment: @Damagon - Right. Here's another way to look at it. `character != 'X'` is true for all characters except "X". Since "or" returns as soon as something is true, the comparison is already complete for everything but "X". In that case, `character != 'O'`. Well, we know the only possible thing it will check is "X", which certainly isn't "O", so it, on the rare occasion that it is evaluated, will be true.